# Error:(22) No resource identifier found for attribute 'aplha' in package 'android'

Tags: java, android

> Error:(22) No resource identifier found for attribute 'aplha' in package 'android'

Also i think because of this i am getting the red `R`.

and also i am getting a second error which i think is because of this it says

> "Execution failed for task':app:processDebugResources'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       android:id="@+id/view_pager"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:aplha=".5"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layoutDots"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="NEXT"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_skip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="SKIP"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: **alpha** is spelled wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Copy this code

```
 <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:alpha=".5"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layoutDots"
    android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```

at

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:aplha=".5"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layoutDots"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```

in your code.

**alpha** is spelled wrong in your code!